# How should I unit test code with a lot of overlap?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I'm relatively new to unit testing. I'm writing a small JavaScript library where I've prioritized a friendly API, which leads to some method overlap for the sake of convenient usage.

As a simple, hypothetical example, consider the following:

```
var BasicMath = function() {};

BasicMath.prototype.multiply = function(numA, numB) {
  return numA * numB;
};

BasicMath.prototype.square = function(num) {
  return this.multiply(num, num);
};
```

How should I unit test this code?

Note that `.square()` is just a convenience method that does nothing but pass along its argument twice to `.multiply()`.

With that in mind, should I:

- write similar (or even identical) unit tests for both methods?
- test that `.square()` calls `.multiply()` with certain arguments? (My understanding is that this is bad practice, since it relies too heavily on the method's implementation details.)
- not test `.square()` at all, since it's essentially redundant to `.multiply()`?
- test only the more general aspects of `.square()` (like argument type, quantity, etc.), to avoid redundancy with `.multiply()`?

Or, some other approach?

Please keep in mind that the code above is just a contrived example - I'm asking a more general question about how to unit test methods with overlapping/redundant functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using jasmine and sinon:

test Multiply like any other method:

```
it('multiplies two numbers', function () {
    math = new BasicMath();
    expect(math.multiply(2,3)).toBe(6);
}
```

with `square`, you want to test that it calls `multiply` passing as both arguments the value of `num` and returns the result returned by `multiply` without performing any other logic:

```
it('squares a number', function () {
    math = new BasicMath();
    math.multiply = sinon.stub();
    math.multiply.withArgs(2,2).returns(4);

    expect(math.square(2)).toBe(4);
}
```

what you do with this is create a reproducible environment using a stub, which will always expect the call to be with two identical args (in this case 2 and 2), which tests that square is sending `num` and `num` (and not `num` and `num + 1` for example), and returns the result of the call to multiply (you could tell the stub to return `'banana'` and check for `'banana'`, what's important is `square` returns whatever `multiply` returns)

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful. Sorry it took so long to accept this answer.